# How to output float result?

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on bash script: need to evaluate an input and then output the result as a float `*.xxx`:

I do:

```
read var1
var2=$((var1))
#echo $var2
echo $((var1))
```

input: `5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7`

my output is 17 but it should be 17.929

How to evaluate it as a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash [only supports integer arithmetic](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html).

In your case, you can use [`bc(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc).

```bash
read var1
var2="$(bc <<<"scale=2;$var1")"
```

Use the scale variable in `bc(1)` to set the number of significant digits (default with is 0).

`bc(1)` is subject to truncation errors ([truncation happens at every step](http://unixetc.co.uk/2014/01/19/bc-rounding-errors/)).

Another option is to use [`calc(1)`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/) (if it is available on your system):

```bash
var2=$(calc -d "_=config(\"display\", 3);$var1")
```

Comment: Thanx! It works.  I have changed to scale=3. One question: I receive 17.928 but it should be 17.929.  How to fix it?

Comment: I have found: printf "%.3f" $var2

Comment: @ZedZip the `printf` method works, there is also the option to use `calc` see my edit.